# Adaptator for RaspberryPi: RJ45 to USB

Tags: networking, ip, usb, raspberry-pi, adapter

With an [adaptator](http://www.dlink.com/fr/fr/home-solutions/connect/usb/dub-e100-high-speed-usb-2-fast-ethernet-adapter) RJ45(female) USB(male) I plug a network cable on my RaspberryPi B and get USB on my PC.
Problem is: They can't recognize each other by  IP (fixed IP).
I find a network connection on each device, but ping don't give anything back.

Any idea :?:

Thank you  ;)

*PS: I keep in mind the volonte to stream on this connexion (with the black PiCam)*

Answer (score 0):

My problem came from the fact that it was not the same subnet mask : roll:
Now that I change it I can connect with putty SSH from the PC to the rpi .
The reverse does not work, but it does not matter.

=> /etc/network/interfaces